# NServiceBus Endpoint Routing Injection

Tags: nservicebus, structuremap, nservicebus4

I am trying to inject my own `IRouteMessagesToEndpoints` in NServiceBus with structure map as I need to redirect various messages to different endpoints depending on some business logic (not via namespace/assembly/type). This would allow it to fire using `bus.Send();` and be configured to our requirements. I thought this was possible, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I have tried using the `Configure.Component()` and `ObjectFactory.Configure()` for the injection, and both run without any exception, but when I debug my implementation of the interface the breakpoint does not hit.

My question is, can it be done this way (there's nothing on the internet that covers this)?  I notice that the EndPointRouter in the GatewayReceiver has a setter, but I cannot work out how to access the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though `IRouteMessagesToEndpoints` is a public interface at the moment is not possible to replace the default implementation, sorry!

Please raise an issue about it in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Gateway/issues/new so we can discuss it better.

Comment: Thanks - at least I can try an alternative.  I know it's not recommended, but is there a way to, in code, change the endpoint that a message is sent to, on the fly rather than on initialization?  If not, I was thinking about a wrapper message class that could be applied that is then routed, but that means handling the command and then resending the content which isn't ideal.

Comment: If you know at send time where to send the message, you can simply use the `bus.Send()` overload that accepts a destination as parameter. In NServiceBus version 6 we are making the [routing plug-able](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing#unicast-routing-type-mapping-layer-dynamic-routes). If that is not enough, you can plug in a [custom behavior](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/customizing-v6) to handle all the routing yourself.